# Joining two tables that have duplicate values but preserve duplicate

Tags: union

I need to do a specific operation on two tables which is:

```
(A - B) U (B)
```

B has duplicate values and A does not have any duplicate values.

In the final union I want to have the duplicate values of B as well. So basically I want to combine both A and B and preserve duplicate values of B in final table

How can we do this in SQL?
I tried

```
A EXCEPT B UNION B
```

but it failed

Comment: `UNION` removes duplicates, while `UNION ALL` does not.

Comment: Instead of tagging multiple database systems, please only tag the one you're actually using, as the answer *can* be dependent and vary on this.